# Passing or returning streams to/from a COM object

Tags: php, delphi, com, stream

Perhaps what I'm trying to do is either impossible or so simple that there is nothing (that I could find) written about it anywhere. At a general level, I'm trying to determine how (if it's possible) to pass a stream to or return a stream from a COM object. Specifically, my COM object is written in Delphi and would typically be used by a PHP script. A use-case would be returning a large block of binary data as a stream from a COM object to the web client via PHP; or writing a large block of binary data received from the web client directly to a COM object (instantiated by a PHP script). Currently, I'm doing these functions by having the COM object and PHP exchange these blocks of data through temp files--the overhead of creating these temp files is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Wow, COM in PHP. I'm amazed. But curious too: how stable is that?

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: It works fine. We use various COM objects to do all sorts of "encapsulated" functions on production PHP systems that are processing millions of transactions per week.

Answer (score 5):

The typical way to work with streams and COM is via the [IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface. I'm not sure about PHP, as I don't do anything with it, but if you can work with COM using it IStream would be the way to go. There's an article and some sample code for IStream in Delphi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11804580).