# How to pass a Delphi Stream to a c/c++ DLL

Tags: c++, delphi, stream

Is it possible to pass a Delphi stream (TStream descendant) to a DLL written in c/c++? DLL will be written in Microsoft c/c++. If that is not possible, how about if we use C++ Builder to create the DLL? Alternatively, are there any Stream (FIFO) classes which can be shared between Microsoft C/C++ and Delphi?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit painful in places but the ActiveX unit Defines IStream which is an interface defines in Win32 API. Exact code escapes me at the moment and I think I might have thrown it away. But TStreamAdapter and TOLEStream were in there somewhere. Mr Google will know the answer.

Comment: @Tony TStreamAdapter goes the wrong way. It takes an `IStream` and adapts it to be a `TStream`.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  `TStreamAdapter` takes a `TStream` as input and wraps it inside an `IStream` implementation.

Comment: @Remy You are right. I can't imagine what came over me. I delete my answer. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: I couldn't remember which was which. :( One was to an Istream the other was from though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using [IStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.IStream) and [TStreamAdapter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStreamAdapter). Here's a quick example (tested in D2007 and XE2):

```
uses
  ActiveX;

procedure TForm1.DoSomething;
var
  MemStream: TMemoryStream;
  ExchangeStream: IStream;
begin
  MemStream := TMemoryFile.Create;
  try
    MemStream.LoadFromFile('C:\Test\SomeFile.txt');
    MemStream.Position := 0;
    ExchangeStream := TStreamAdapter.Create(MemStream) as IStream;
    // Pass ExchangeStream to C++ DLL here, and do whatever else
  finally
    MemStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Just in case, if you need to go the other way (receiving an `IStream` from C/C++), you can use [TOleStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AxCtrls.TOleStream) to get from that `IStream` to a Delphi `TStream`.

Comment: That accords with a vague memory of doing this once upon a time. +1

Comment: @Ken White: Thanks for the answer. It is not hard once you know :-)

Answer (score 4):

- Code compiled by Microsoft C/C++ cannot call methods directly on a Delphi object. You would have to wrap the methods up and present, to the C++ code, an `interface`, for example.
- Code compiled by C++ Builder can call methods directly on a Delphi object.

In general, wrapping up a Delphi class and presenting it as an `interface` is not completely trivial.  One reason why you can't just expose the raw methods via an interface is that the Delphi methods using the `register` calling convention which is proprietary to Embarcadero compilers. You'd need to use a [calling convention](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions) that is understood by the Microsoft compiler, e.g. `stdcall`.

Another complication comes with exceptions. You would need to make sure that your interface methods did not throw exceptions since your C++ code can't be expected to catch them. One option would be to use Delphi's [`safecall`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions) calling convention. The `safecall` calling convention is `stdcall` but with an added twist that converts exceptions into `HRESULT` values.

All rather straight forward in concept, but probably requiring a certain amount of tedious boilerplate code.

Thankfully, in the case of `TStream`, you can use `TStreamAdapter` to expose the Delphi stream as a COM `IStream`. In fact, the source code for this small class shows how to handle the issues I describe above.

Comment: -1, because `TStreamAdapter` was written specifically to wrap a `TStream` in a COM-compatible `IStream`, which can be used by any language that can use COM.

Comment: @Ken Thank you, you are quite right. I elected to keep this answer because of the two bullet points. And also the more general advice for implementing an adapter to a COM interface. That could be useful for people that want something other than a stream.

Comment: Downvote removed, because the incorrect portion was corrected. :-)