# Load .png to TImage in Embarcadero C++Builder XE5

Tags: c++, png, timage, c++builder-xe5

I need to load a .png image because i need it's transparency. It's not an option to convert it for example in bmp because i lose it's transparency.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an include for `stdimage.hpp`.

At designtime, this will make .png files available in the `Image.Picture` dialog. At runtime, you can create and load a TPngImage with the file, and assign it to the `Image.Picture`.

```
#include <stdimage.hpp>

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
  TPngImage* img = new TPngImage();
  img->LoadFromFile("C:\\Images\\calculator.png");
  Image1->Picture->Assign(img);
  delete img;
}
```

(Delphi code and explanation included as well as C++ Builder, because the `TImage` and `TPngImage` are both Delphi classes and therefore it's relevant, and because C++ Builder users should be pretty familiar with translating Delphi code as the entire VCL is built on it. Also, as `TImage` is a Delphi VCL component, a Delphi user may find the question and find the information useful as well.)

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Png: TPngImage;
begin
  Png := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    Png.LoadFromFile('C:\Images\calculator.png');
    Image1.Picture.Assign(Png);
  finally
    Png.Free;
  end;
end;
```

More info in the [XE5 documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage)

Comment: My fault, i'm using XE5. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I get "Type name expected" when I try this line:
`TPngImage *Image;`

Comment: C++ Builder has the VCL, and therefore has TPngImage. It's contained in the VCL.Imaging package in XE5.

Comment: @David. The poster is familiar with the VCL, and the question is tagged **C++ Builder**. The necessary component is in a VCL package. Thanks as always for your input.

Comment: Read my answer. It explains why Delphi code. (I don't have Builder installed on this machine, and won't post Builder code I can't compile and test first.) I'll be glad to update the answer with Builder code once I get to a machine that has it available.

Comment: You also missed the comments I deleted once a tag/subject discrepancy was cleared up (the title said Builder XE5, the tag said Builder 5).

Comment: Never mind. It seemed clear to me all along that this was a C++ question. Perhaps I got that wrong.

Comment: @David: Then it should also be clear to you that the vast majority of people using C++Builder can translate the equivalent Delphi code (as I can translate the majority of C++Builder code to Delphi) when it relates to the VCL or RTL.

Comment: `Vcl.Imaging.pngimage` in uses clauses for delphi.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ Builder the code might look like this:

```
#include <pngimage.hpp>
....
std::auto_ptr<TPngImage> img(new TPngImage());
img->LoadFromFile(...);
Image1->Picture->Assign(img);
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile in C++ Builder. (Tested in Builder XE2.)

Comment: Yes, starting with these:  E2316 'auto_ptr' is not a member of 'std',
E2108 Improper use of typedef 'TPngImage',
E2268 Call to undefined function 'img'
E2288 Pointer to structure required on left side of -> or ->*

Comment: Obviously you need to include the `memory` header for `auto_ptr`. That goes without saying!

Comment: Doesn't go without saying for me, any more than my (clearly sufficient) Delphi code was acceptable to you. (However, I didn't downvote, as you'll notice.)

Comment: @ken auto_ptr is one of the C++ smart pointers. These are the idiomatic way to manage memory and avoid leaks. C++ has no finally so traditionally uses RAII. Your C++ code leaks in the face of an exception. Hence the smart pointer.

Comment: I know what "auto_ptr" is, actually. My C++ code is the basic information needed to answer the question. The poster should be able to use it properly.

Comment: @ken Oh I thought you did not know that. Otherwise you'd have known how to compile the code. Everyone omits includes and uses in excerpts. Your answer is an exemplar. Nothing wrong with that. Why did you protect the resource in the Delphi but not the C++?

Comment: Because I presumed the poster would know how to do so. My point was that you were quick to immediately downvote my answer (because I was unwilling to post code that I hadn't compiled myself), and yet you did so. ("the code *might look like this*"?). I also note that, even though I addressed the reason for your downvote and corrected the issue, you haven't reverted the downvote.

Comment: @Ken It seems unfair for you to make such a presumption and yet object to me making one. I'll reverse the DV when the Delphi code has gone. And tidy up comments.

Comment: @KenWhite Once an answer is posted, it is fair to judge it. And "might look like this" does not mean "might compile, or might not". It means, "one might choose to write it like this".

Comment: The Delphi code is immaterial. If the poster is familiar with Delphi, it might be useful. As it relates to the VCL (TImage), it's relevant here regardless of the question being about Builder (and a Delphi user might run across it and find it helpful). I can point to a post by you that not only doesn't answer the question asked, but was left up after I posted the correct answer where you said "Leaving in case someone finds it useful in the future". I really don't care whether you revert your vote or not; I was noting the hypocrisy.

Comment: @Ken Your crusade is a bit odd.

Comment: And in that post I mention, ironically it's a case where you posted a wrong answer, I downvoted accordingly, you modified your answer to remove the incorrect (and relevant) part, and I reverted my downvote. Wnat "crusade"?

Comment: @Ken It's hard for me to comment on a post that is not identified. Your answer should not have any Delphi in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803444/how-to-pass-a-delphi-stream-to-a-c-c-dll/11804580#11804580. See in particular the revision history of your answer and the comments it contains. Your answer there has nothing to do with the question asked; it's a generic "this might be useful" answer. It shouldn't exist at all, but it does (because you decided it should). My Delphi code is in fact pertinent (and relevant) to the question, as it concerns TImage and TPngImage, both of which are **Delphi** components.

Comment: @Ken That answer does answer the question. *Is it possible to pass a Delphi stream (TStream descendant) to a DLL written in c/c++?* Actually you answer there does not address that point. Which I think is why I left the answer there. Because it answered the question that was asked. Your answer solves the problem. Your crusade is tedious.

Comment: @Ken But that's a good example of an answer that was weak, was criticised justifiably, and was improved. Please can you just remove the Delphi from your answer here, thus making it better, and then we can move on.

Comment: Except I *don't agree* that it would make the answer *better* by removing it. If I decide to arbitrarily tell you to remove something from an answer you write (and you feel that information is relevant), are you going to remove it? I highly doubt it.

Comment: @Ken We clearly disagree. You think the Delphi code makes the answer better. That's clearly up to you. So you want to keep the code. So I leave the downvote because I disagree. I feel it makes the answer worse. So be it.